# How to make the SDL_ttf work with the SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I've recently switch from SDL 1.0 to 2.0 for some program necessity. I've successfully managed to make it work as well as SDL_image that I use. However, for some reason, SDL_ttf 2.0 does not work on my program. I have paid attention to use the function of the 2.0 and not the 1.0 and tested the ttf with programs that weren't my owns, nothing worked. Usually, the program runs until it has to print text then it closes and send "process returned -1073741819" which is for what I know an error message in a program for it should return 0. I tried both x64 and x86 but none worked though the x86 seemed to give better results.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

int main()
{
  SDL_Surface *logo = NULL, *Wreed, *Reminder, *ecran = NULL;
  SDL_Window *window = NULL;
  SDL_Texture *textureLogo = NULL, *textureWreed = NULL, *textureReminder = NULL;
  SDL_Rect positionLogo = {1100/2 - 600/2, 700/2 - 600/2, 600, 600}, /*positionWreed,*/ positionReminder;
  TTF_Font *police = NULL;
  SDL_Color couleur = {0,0,0};
  SDL_Renderer* renderer;


police = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 40);

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Wreed Reminder", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1100, 700, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
ecran = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

Wreed = TTF_RenderText_Blended(police, "Wreed", couleur);
textureWreed = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Wreed);
SDL_Rect positionWreed = {10, 10, 10, 10};
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, textureWreed, NULL, &positionWreed);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

SDL_Delay(5000);
}
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, please help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Did you do a complete rebuild after making your changes?  Is this a Windows system?

Comment: I did rebuild the program, it did nothing and I use a Window system indeed. For the question, i'm sorry, I didn't know what else to put. After all, my problem is that the SDL_ttf 2.0 doesn't work with the SDL2, isn't it ? But if you have any idea how to ask it properly, i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Where's your [`TTF_Init()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC8) call? "[TTF_Init()] must be called before using other functions in this library, except TTF_WasInit."

Comment: Why aren't you checking if `police` is NULL before using it?

Comment: The reason I asked about Windows was because a [search for that error code](https://www.google.com/search?q=1073741819) turns up references to a file system error.

Comment: I tried putting TTF_Init() and TTF_Quit() in the program, didn't work. Then I checked if `police` was NULL, it wasn't and led to the same result. For the file system error, I haven't find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it is because of the installation. I'll tell you what I did, if you don't see something I should have done, please tell me. So I decompressed the ZIP of the ttf, I've put the SDL_ttf.h in the include file of the SDL2 file, my SDL_ttf.lib in my lib file and the dll in the project file. Then, I linked the .lib in the linker settings, build options. Finally I included the SDL_ttf.h in the program. Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know quite what happened but I reinstalled the latest version of the ttf and set the x86 but it didn't work, so I tried x64, just in case. Didn't work either. Then, I reset the x86 and, surprise, it is working.